# Getting an error while calling linkedin API

Tags: vue.js, linkedin-api

Getting an error while calling linkedin API. Like,

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me' from origin 'https://localhost:8085' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I have also added headers like,

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
"Access-Control-Max-Age": "1800",
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "content-type",
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods":"PUT, POST, GET, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
"Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LinkedIn seems to have disabled querying from browser. Do the query in backend and then send the response to your frontend application via your own API.

Comment: what's the quickest / simplest way to set this up? I just want to test for development until I know it works...thanks!